# Calling a method outside class statically, passing other method's output as parameter

Tags: php, classes, static

I have this class:

```
class adminTemplate {

    public static function load() 
    {
        return new self();
    }

    public function sidebarGuide()
    {
        return 'content'; // Very long html markup
    }

    public function wrapSidebars($content)
    {
        ob_start();
        echo "<div class='sidebar wrapper'>";
        echo $content;
        echo "</div>";
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output;
    }

    // Other methods here

}
```

Somewhere in my script, I have to call `wrapSidebars` using `sidebarGuide`'s output as parameter:

```
echo adminTemplate::load()->wrapSidebars(adminTemplate::load()->sidebarGuide());
```

It works, but I'm pretty confident there is a more appropriate way.

1. Is there a proper way of passing methods'output as other method's parameter in a class loaded "statically"?
2. Besides that, is there a more elegant code structure to accomplish the same "task"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation confuses me a bit, and maybe it's because we aren't able to see the whole picture.

First, I don't understand the purpose of the `adminTemplate::load()` method. It is basically just a constructor. If you eventually plan to add more complexity to it (use it as a builder, factory, or to make `adminTemplate` a singleton), then it makes sense, but as it stands now, you might as well just use a constructor.

The relationship between `sidebarGuide` and `wrapSidebars` is not totally clear either. If `wrapSidebars` is only ever called with the result of `sidebarGuide` as a parameter, then drop the parameter and convert `sidebarGuide` into a private helper method. If, on the other hand, `wrapSidebars` can be called with more than the output of `sidebarGuide`, but `sidebarGuide` is always wrapped with `wrapSidebars`, simply wrap the return value of `sidebarGuide`:

```
public function sidebarGuide()
{
    return $this->wrapSidebars('content'); // Very long html markup
}
```

If sidebars are not always wrapped, but only sidebars are wrapped, you could create a decorator class to wrap around your `adminTemplate` instance that gets the content from the delegate, and returns the content, wrapped.

```
class adminTemplate
{
    # Constructor

    function sidebarGuide() { ... }
}

class TemplateDecorator
{
    protected $template;

    # Constructor

    protected function wrapSidebars() { ... }

    function sidebarGuide() {
        return $this->wrapSidebars($this->template->sidebarGuide());
    }
}
```

The one other thing that confuses me is the implementation of `wrapSidebars`. You use `ob_*` functions and `echo`s, but all of the pieces are already strings? You could more simply use string concatenation/interpolation:

```
public function wrapSidebars($content)
{
    return "<div class='sidebar wrapper'>$content</div>";
}
```

There may be a (*very*) minor difference in performance, but the simplicity of the code should outweigh the micro-optimization.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `load()` every time you call either `sidebarGuide` or `wrapSidebars`. Are you doing anything other than returning an instance of the class? If not, then just instantiate the class and making `load()` a construct would be more ideal. Doing so, your class would look like:

```
class adminTemplate {
    public function __construct(){}

    public function sidebarGuide(){
        return "content"; # Very long html markup
    }

    public function wrapSidebars($content){
        ob_start();
        echo "<div class='sidebar wrapper'>";
        echo $content;
        echo "</div>";
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output;
    }
}
```

You would then use it as follows:

```
$adminTemplate = new adminTemplate();
$adminTemplate->sidebarGuide();
$adminTemplate->wrapSidebars($adminTemplate->sidebarGuide());
```

If you wanted, you could even store the return value of `sidebarGuide()` in a property of the class so that you could call `wrapSidebars()` without injecting `sidebarGuide()`, as follows:

```
class adminTemplate {
    private $sidebarGuideReturnValue

    public function __construct(){}

    public function sidebarGuide(){
        $this->sidebarGuideReturnValue = "content"; # Very long html markup

        return $this->sidebarGuideReturnValue;
    }

    public function wrapSidebars($content = ""){
        # Make $content an optional parameter. If its not set, grab the property
        $content = ($content ? $content : $this->sidebarGuideReturnValue);

        ob_start();
        echo "<div class='sidebar wrapper'>";
        echo $content;
        echo "</div>";
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output;
    }
}
```

If you know that would only be calling `sidebarGuide()` exclusively as a param to `wrapSidebars()`, you could even relegate `sidebarGuide()`'s to a private called on instantiation in the construct, or move its body to the construct itself.

One question that bothers me though is, is there any specific reason you want to use static `load()`? Or just because it looks nice?

Comment: You probably should not have answered this question while it contained example code.  The OP has just now changed the names, so you may update your answer accordingly (it doesn't count as invalidation since the edit was in response to the closure).

Comment: Since I don't use autoloader (yet), the static `load()` allows me to bypass class instantiation, which I dislike. Storing a method output in a class poperty with the constructor is interesting, but will this lead a `sidebarGuide` call for every class instance, even when `wrapSidebars` is not needed?

Comment: @Jamal True. I had posted the answer on the page prior to the closing (only noticed closing after reloading the page). Will update to reflect new code. @Jolly Roger - Using an autoloader helps in loading the class, not in instantiating the class (read, you still have to instantiate after a basic autoload). Also, it's not about what you like/dislike, its about best practice...and calling load() every time only adds overhead and makes your code run slower (you're creating a new object every call). Also, yes it'll create `sidebarGuide` for the instance.

Comment: @jsanc623 Fair enough, you're right. And speaking about best practice, what about making methods static? So: `adminTemplate::wrapSidebars(adminTemplate::sidebarGuide());`?

Comment: You could do that - but then you'd lose state (remember a static method is an immutable method, then the drawback is that mutating operations need to copy an object instead of changing it in-place. That can get really expensive, really quickly). Perhaps read up on the Facade Design Pattern (http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade/php)?

Answer (score 1):

I like @jsanc623's answer, but I would also add into the code a private static variable $_instance, and using a similar loader function:

```
class adminTemplate {

    private static $_instance;

    private $sidebarGuideReturnValue

    private function __construct(){}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!(self::$_instance instanceof adminTemplate)) self::$_instance = new adminTemplate();
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function sidebarGuide(){
        $this->sidebarGuideReturnValue = "content"; # Very long html markup

        return $this->sidebarGuideReturnValue;
    }

    public function wrapSidebars($content = ""){
        # Make $content an optional parameter. If its not set, grab the property
        $content = ($content ? $content : $this->sidebarGuideReturnValue);

        ob_start();
        echo "<div class='sidebar wrapper'>";
        echo $content;
        echo "</div>";
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output;
    }
}
```

From there, you'll be able to effortlessly call `adminTemplate::getInstance()->wrapSidebars();`